# Minikube can't run container with volume

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

I tried run cointainer with volume locally on minikube, but I receive error.
`2022/01/15 12:12:06 open todo.db/lock: permission denied`
I give full permision to todo.db

```
root@DESKTOP-JBBNTB7:/usr/local/go/src/todo# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 jarek jarek 4096 Jan 15 12:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jarek jarek 4096 Jan 15 12:56 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jarek jarek    0 Jan 15 12:56 todo.db
```

When I run `docker run -p 8000:8000 -v todo_db:/usr/local/go/src/todo/todo.db prologic/todo`
I receive `2022/01/15 12:12:06 open todo.db/lock: permission denied`
I tried execute this command as root and also as user jarek.
What is wrong?

https://hub.docker.com/r/prologic/todo

Comment: What user is your container running as?  You're using `-v volume_name:/container/path` named-volume syntax; is this what you intend?  If you want the file to be stored on your host, have you done the Minikube [Mounting filesystems](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/) setup?

Comment: (You tagged this with "kubernetes"; is there anything Kubernetes-specific in this question, or are you just using Minikube as a way to get a Linux Docker VM?)  (In the wake of the Docker Desktop licensing issue, I'm actually using Minikube for most of my plain-Docker work.)

Comment: There is something not correct with file : todo.db , Because it shows the size as "0"